# Erro Undefined variable Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Tenho um sistema de gerenciamento de campeonatos de futebol, mas estou tendo problemas para exibir os dados do campeonato especifico, já pesquisei sobre o erro, mas não encontrei onde está faltando a chamada de variavel, desde já agradeço a ajuda!
Obs: O arquivo listar está pela metade.

ErrorException (E_ERROR)
HELP
Undefined variable: grupos (View: /var/www/vhosts/uppererp.com.br/ligafutsal/app/views/admin/campeonatos/jogos/listar-jogos.blade.php)

Aqui está o link, caso queiram acompanhar o erro: http://liga.uppererp.com.br/admin/campeonatos/jogos/22

este é o arquivo listar-jogos.blade.php

```html
@extends('admin/template')
@section('content')
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="{{ URL::route('dashboard') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Campeonatos</a></li>
            <li class="active">Jogos</li>
          </ol>
          <h1 class="pull-left">Jogos</h1>
          @if($campeonato->id_campeonato == 1)
          <a  target="_blank" href="http://ovre.com.br/liga/REGULAMENTO%20MUNICIPAL%202015.docx" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Download Regulamento</a>
          @endif
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        @if( Session::has('sucesso') )
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{{ Session::get('sucesso') }}}
            </div>
        @endif
        @if( Session::has('warning') )
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                {{ Session::get('warning') }}
            </div>
        @endif
        @if ( count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Erro: </strong>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $e)
                   {{ $e }}
                @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        
        @foreach($campeonato->getGrupos as $grupo)
        @if(!isset($nr_divisao) || $grupo->nr_divisao != $nr_divisao)     
        <?php $grupos[] = $grupo->nr_divisao ?>
        <li><a href="#div{{ $grupo->nr_divisao }}" data-toggle="tab">{{ GrupoAdminController::getDivisao($grupo->nr_divisao, $grupo->id_campeonato) }}</a></li>
        @endif
        <?php $nr_divisao = $grupo->nr_divisao; ?>
        @endforeach
        <li><a href="#divCartoes" data-toggle="tab">Listagem Cartões Amarelos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divRanking" data-toggle="tab">Artilheiros</a></li>
      </ul>
      
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <hr>
        <div id="divRanking" class="tab-pane">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Ranking jogadores</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Jogador</th>
                    <th>Gols</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php $i = 1; ?>
                  @foreach(CampeonatoController::getArtilheiros($campeonato->id_campeonato) as $jogador)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{{ $jogador->nm_jogador }}} ({{{ JogadorController::getNomeEquipe($jogador->id_jogador, $campeonato->id_campeonato) }}})</td>
                    <td>{{{ $jogador->total_gol }}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php ++$i; ?>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divCartoes" class="tab-pane">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Cartões</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Jogador</th>
                    <th>Cartões</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php $i = 1; ?>
                  @foreach(CampeonatoController::getCartoesCampeonato($campeonato->id_campeonato) as $jogador)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{{ $jogador->nm_jogador }}} ({{{ JogadorController::getNomeEquipe($jogador->id_jogador, $campeonato->id_campeonato) }}})</td>
                    <td>{{{ $jogador->total_cartao }}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php ++$i; ?>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @foreach($grupos as $divisao)
          <div id="div{{$divisao}}" class="tab-pane">
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <hr>

              @if($campeonato->getJogosFinal)
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Final</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
              @foreach($campeonato->getJogosFinal()->where('nr_divisao', '=', $divisao)->get() as $jogo)
                  <a href="{{{ URL::route('admin-jogo', $jogo->id_jogo) }}}">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h3 class="panel-title">{{ InputsController::trataData('Y-m-d H:i:s', $jogo->dthr_jogo, 'd/m/Y H:i') }} | {{{ ($jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()) ? $jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()->nome_local : 'SEM LOCAL DEFINIDO' }}} | {{{ ($jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()) ? $jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()->endereco_local : 'SEM LOCAL DEFINIDO' }}}</h3>
                          <hr>
                          {{ ($jogo->flg_wo == 1) ? '<span class="label label-danger">W.O</span>' : '' }}
                          {{ ($jogo->flg_empate == 1) ? '<span class="label label-warning">Empate</span>' : '' }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="col-md-8">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorHome()->first()->nm_equipe, 18) }}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="border-left: gray">
                                                        @if($jogo->flg_wo == 1)
                              @if($jogo->id_equipe1 == $jogo->id_vencedor)
                                W
                              @else
                                O
                              @endif
                            @else
                              {{ $jogo->saldo_gols_1 }}
                            @endif

                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorAway()->first()->nm_equipe, 18) }}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="border-left: gray">
                            @if($jogo->flg_wo == 1)
                              @if($jogo->id_equipe2 == $jogo->id_vencedor)
                                W
                              @else
                                O
                              @endif
                            @else
                              {{ $jogo->saldo_gols_2 }}
                            @endif

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
              @endforeach
              </div>
              </div>
            @endif



              @if($campeonato->getJogosSemiFinal)
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Semi-Final</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
              @foreach($campeonato->getJogosSemiFinal()->where('nr_divisao', '=', $divisao)->get() as $jogo)
                  <a href="{{{ URL::route('admin-jogo', $jogo->id_jogo) }}}">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h3 class="panel-title">{{ InputsController::trataData('Y-m-d H:i:s', $jogo->dthr_jogo, 'd/m/Y H:i') }} | {{{ ($jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()) ? $jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()->nome_local : 'SEM LOCAL DEFINIDO' }}} | {{{ ($jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()) ? $jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()->endereco_local : 'SEM LOCAL DEFINIDO' }}}</h3>
                          <hr>
                          {{ ($jogo->flg_wo == 1) ? '<span class="label label-danger">W.O</span>' : '' }}
                          {{ ($jogo->flg_empate == 1) ? '<span class="label label-warning">Empate</span>' : '' }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="col-md-8">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorHome()->first()->nm_equipe, 18) }}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="border-left: gray">
                            @if($jogo->flg_wo == 1)
                              @if($jogo->id_equipe1 == $jogo->id_vencedor)
                                W
                              @else
                                O
                              @endif
                            @else
                              {{ $jogo->saldo_gols_1 }}
                            @endif

                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorAway()->first()->nm_equipe, 18) }}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="border-left: gray">
                            @if($jogo->flg_wo == 1)
                              @if($jogo->id_equipe2 == $jogo->id_vencedor)
                                W
                              @else
                                O
                              @endif
                            @else
                              {{ $jogo->saldo_gols_2 }}
                            @endif

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
              @endforeach
              </div>
              </div>
            @endif

              @if($campeonato->getJogosQuartasFinal)
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Quartas de Final</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
              @foreach($campeonato->getJogosQuartasFinal()->where('nr_divisao', '=', $divisao)->get() as $jogo)
                  <a href="{{{ URL::route('admin-jogo', $jogo->id_jogo) }}}">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h3 class="panel-title">{{ InputsController::trataData('Y-m-d H:i:s', $jogo->dthr_jogo, 'd/m/Y H:i') }} | {{{ ($jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()) ? $jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()->nome_local : 'SEM LOCAL DEFINIDO' }}} | {{{ ($jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()) ? $jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()->endereco_local : 'SEM LOCAL DEFINIDO' }}}</h3>
                          <hr>
                          {{ ($jogo->flg_wo == 1) ? '<span class="label label-danger">W.O</span>' : '' }}
                          {{ ($jogo->flg_empate == 1) ? '<span class="label label-warning">Empate</span>' : '' }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="col-md-8">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorHome()->first()->nm_equipe, 18) }}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="border-left: gray">
                            @if($jogo->flg_wo == 1)
                              @if($jogo->id_equipe1 == $jogo->id_vencedor)
                                W
                              @else
                                O
                              @endif
                            @else
                              {{ $jogo->saldo_gols_1 }}
                            @endif
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorAway()->first()->nm_equipe, 18) }}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="border-left: gray">
                            @if($jogo->flg_wo == 1)
                              @if($jogo->id_equipe2 == $jogo->id_vencedor)
                                W
                              @else
                                O
                              @endif
                            @else
                              {{ $jogo->saldo_gols_2 }}
                            @endif

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
              @endforeach
              </div>
              </div>
            @endif
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr>


              @if($campeonato->getJogosOitavas)
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Oitavas de Final</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
              @foreach($campeonato->getJogosOitavas()->where('nr_divisao', '=', $divisao)->get() as $jogo)
                  <a href="{{{ URL::route('admin-jogo', $jogo->id_jogo) }}}">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                          <h3 class="panel-title">{{ InputsController::trataData('Y-m-d H:i:s', $jogo->dthr_jogo, 'd/m/Y H:i') }} | {{{ ($jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()) ? $jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()->nome_local : 'SEM LOCAL DEFINIDO' }}} | {{{ ($jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()) ? $jogo->getLocalJogo()->first()->endereco_local : 'SEM LOCAL DEFINIDO' }}}</h3>
                          <hr>
                          {{ ($jogo->flg_wo == 1) ? '<span class="label label-danger">W.O</span>' : '' }}
                          {{ ($jogo->flg_empate == 1) ? '<span class="label label-warning">Empate</span>' : '' }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                          <div class="col-md-8">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorHome()->first()->nm_equipe, 18) }}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="border-left: gray">
                            @if($jogo->flg_wo == 1)
                              @if($jogo->id_equipe1 == $jogo->id_vencedor)
                                W
                              @else
                                O
                              @endif
                            @else
                              {{ $jogo->saldo_gols_1 }}
                            @endif
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-8">{{{ str_limit($jogo->getJogadorAway()->first()->nm_equipe, 18) }}}</div>
                          <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="border-left: gray">
                            @if($jogo->flg_wo == 1)
                              @if($jogo->id_equipe2 == $jogo->id_vencedor)
                                W
                              @else
                                O
                              @endif
                            @else
                              {{ $jogo->saldo_gols_2 }}
                            @endif

                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </a>
              @endforeach
              </div>
              </div>
            @endif
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <hr>


            @foreach($campeonato->getGrupos()->where('nr_divisao', '=', $divisao)->get() as $grupo)
              <?php
                $rodadas = '';
              ?>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Grupo {{ $grupo->nm_grupo }}</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <table class="table table-bordered table{{$divisao}}">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"></th>
                        <th>PG</th>
                        <th>JG</th>
                        <th>V</th>
                        <th>E</th>
                        <th>D</th>
                        <th>GP</th>
                        <th>GC</th>
                        <th>SG</th>
                        <th>IT</th>
                        <th>AV</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
```

este é o arquivo GrupoAdminController.php

```html
<?php

class GrupoAdminController extends BaseController {

 public function listarGeracaoGrupos($id) {

     $equipe = Equipe::find(Auth::id());

     $totalJogadores = Jogador::join('transferencias', 'transferencias.id_jogador', '=', 'jogadores.id_jogador')
                                            ->where('transferencias.id_equipe_atual', '=', $equipe->id_equipe)
                                            ->where('flg_aprovado', '=', 1)
                                            ->groupBy('transferencias.id_jogador')
                                            ->orderBy('id_transferencia', 'DESC')
                                            ->count();

       $totalCampeonatosEmAberto = Campeonato::where('dt_inicio_inscricoes', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
               ->where('dt_fim_inscricoes', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
               ->where('flg_ativo', '=', 1)
               ->count();


        $campeonato = Campeonato::find($id);
        $equipesInscritas = Equipe::select('nm_equipe', 'equipes.id_equipe')
              ->join('inscricoes', 'inscricoes.id_equipe', '=', 'equipes.id_equipe')
              ->where('id_campeonato', '=', $id)
              ->where('inscricoes.flg_ativo', '=', 1)
              ->where('equipes.flg_ativo', '=', 1)
              ->get(); 

     return View::make('admin/campeonatos/geracao/gerar-grupos')->with(
             array(
                 'equipe' => $equipe,
                 'totalJogadores' => $totalJogadores,
                 'totalCampeonatosEmAberto' => $totalCampeonatosEmAberto,
              'totalInscricoes' => InscricaoController::getTotalnscricao(),
              'campeonato' => $campeonato,
              'equipesInscritas' => $equipesInscritas,
             )
         );
 }

 public function gerarGrupos($id) {
  
  $campeonato = Campeonato::find($id);
  $combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics;

  // Gerando os Grupos e Grupos Equipes
  foreach(Input::get('total_grupos') as $c => $valor) {
   $grupos = range('A', 'Z'); // Definindo o nome dos grupos (A,B,C,D,E,F...)
   if(array_key_exists($c, Input::get('equipe'))) {
     $equipes = Input::get('equipe')[$c];
     $totalG = $valor; // Total de grupos
     $timesPorGrupo = (count(Input::get('equipe')[$c]) / $totalG); //Saber quantos times vão cair por grupo
     $resto = count(Input::get('equipe')[$c]) % $totalG; // Pegando o resto da divisão
     $a = 0;
     $chave = [];
     for($i=1;$i<=$totalG;$i++) {
      if($i == 1) {
       if($resto > 0) {
        $chave[$c][$grupos[$i-1]] = array_slice($equipes,0,$timesPorGrupo+1);
        $resto--;
        $a =  count($chave[$c][$grupos[$i-1]]);
       } else {
        $chave[$c][$grupos[$i-1]] = array_slice($equipes,0,$timesPorGrupo);
        $a = count($chave[$c][$grupos[$i-1]]);
       }
      } else {
       if($resto > 0) {
        $chave[$c][$grupos[$i-1]] = array_slice($equipes,$a,$timesPorGrupo+1);
        $resto--;
        $a += count($chave[$c][$grupos[$i-1]]);
       } else {
        $chave[$c][$grupos[$i-1]] = array_slice($equipes,$a,$timesPorGrupo);
        $a += count($chave[$c][$grupos[$i-1]]);
       }
      }
     }

    // Inserindo os Grupos e Suas Respectivas Equipes
    $divisoes = array('e' => 1, 'p' => 2, 's' => 3, 't' => 4, 'q' => 5);
    foreach($chave as $divisao => $grupos) {
     foreach($grupos as $chave => $equipes) {
      $grupo = new Grupo;
      $grupo->id_campeonato = $campeonato->id_campeonato;
      $grupo->nm_grupo = $chave;
      $grupo->nr_fase = 1;
      $grupo->nr_divisao = $divisoes[$divisao];
      $grupo->save();
      foreach($equipes as $equipe) {
       $grupoEquipe = new GrupoEquipe;
       $grupoEquipe->id_equipe = $equipe;
       $grupoEquipe->id_grupo = $grupo->id_grupo;
       $grupoEquipe->save();
      }
     }
    }

    // Salvando o Andamento do Campeonato
    $campeonato->flg_andamento = 1; // Grupos Gerados
    $campeonato->save();

   }
  }

  return Redirect::to(URL::route('gerenciar-grupos', $campeonato->id_campeonato));
 }

 public function gerarJogos($id) {

  $campeonato = Campeonato::find($id);
  $combinatorics = new Math_Combinatorics;

  // Gerando os jogos
  foreach($campeonato->getGrupos as $grupo) {
   foreach($grupo->getEquipes as $equipe) {
    $g[$grupo->id_grupo][] = $equipe->id_equipe;
   }
  }

  foreach($g as $idGrupo => $arrayEquipes) {
   $combinations[$idGrupo][] = $combinatorics->combinations($arrayEquipes, 2);
  }

  foreach($combinations as $grupo => $jogos) {
   $grupo = Grupo::find($grupo);
   foreach($jogos[0] as $eqs) {
    reset($eqs);
    $eq1 = $eqs[key($eqs)];
    
    end($eqs);
    $eq2 = $eqs[key($eqs)];

    $jogo = new Jogo;
    $jogo->id_campeonato = $campeonato->id_campeonato;
    $jogo->id_equipe1 = $eq1;
    $jogo->id_equipe2 = $eq2;
    $jogo->id_grupo = $grupo->id_grupo;
    $jogo->flg_tp_jogo = 1;
    $jogo->flg_ativo = 1;
    $jogo->save();
   }
  }

  $campeonato->flg_andamento = 2; // Jogos Gerados
  $campeonato->save();

  return Redirect::to(URL::route('gerar-rodadas', $campeonato->id_campeonato))->with(array('sucesso' => 'Grupos gerados com sucesso!'));
 }

 static public function getDivisao($divisao, $campeonato) {
  
  $campeonato = Campeonato::find($campeonato);


  if($campeonato->flg_tp_campeonato != 1 && $campeonato->flg_tp_campeonato != 2) {
   return '-';
  }

  switch ($divisao) {
   case 1:
    return 'Especial';
    break;
   
   case 2:
    return 'Primeira Divisão';
    break;

   case 3:
    return 'Segunda Divisão';
    break;

   case 4:
    return 'Terceira Divisão';
    break;

   case 5:
    return 'Quarta Divisão';
    break;
  }
 }

 public function gerenciarGrupos($id) {

  $campeonato = Campeonato::find($id);
  $equipe = Equipe::find(Auth::id());

     $totalJogadores = Jogador::join('transferencias', 'transferencias.id_jogador', '=', 'jogadores.id_jogador')
                                            ->where('transferencias.id_equipe_atual', '=', $equipe->id_equipe)
                                            ->where('flg_aprovado', '=', 1)
                                            ->groupBy('transferencias.id_jogador')
                                            ->orderBy('id_transferencia', 'DESC')
                                            ->count();

       $totalCampeonatosEmAberto = Campeonato::where('dt_inicio_inscricoes', '<=', date('Y-m-d'))
               ->where('dt_fim_inscricoes', '>=', date('Y-m-d'))
               ->where('flg_ativo', '=', 1)
               ->count();



  return View::make('admin/campeonatos/geracao/gerenciar-grupos')->with(
        array(
            'equipe' => $equipe,
            'totalJogadores' => $totalJogadores,
            'totalCampeonatosEmAberto' => $totalCampeonatosEmAberto,
            'totalInscricoes' => InscricaoController::getTotalnscricao(),
            'campeonato' => $campeonato,
        )
    );


 }

 public function gerarGruposEquipes() {

  $equipe = Equipe::find(Auth::id());
  $campeonato = Campeonato::find(Input::get('campeonato'));
  
  foreach(Input::get('equipe') as $id => $equipes) {
   GrupoEquipe::where('id_grupo', '=', $id)->delete();
   foreach($equipes as $e) {
    $grupoEquipe = new GrupoEquipe;
    $grupoEquipe->id_equipe = $e;
    $grupoEquipe->id_grupo = $id;
    $grupoEquipe->save();
   }
  }

  return Redirect::to(URL::route('gerar-jogos', $campeonato->id_campeonato));
 }
}
```

Comment: Tem um foreach que está assim "@foreach($grupos as $divisao)" no seu blade, acredito que deveria ser assim  "@foreach($campeonato->getGrupos as $divisao)". Você não está especificando quem é $grupos, precisa especificar.

Comment: nossa cara, deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu blade tem um foreach que está assim:

```
@foreach($grupos as $divisao)
```

Substitua, e deixe-o assim:

```
@foreach($campeonato->getGrupos as $divisao)
```

Você não está especificando quem é $grupos, precisa especificar.

Comment: eu até te daria uma classificação, mas alguém negativou minha pergunta e agora não tenho reputação suficiente :(, muito obrigado novamente pela ajuda!